# How to search entries in the dialer contacts by both first name and last name?

Tags: contacts, phone-app, search

I have Android 10 on my Nokia phone which uses AndroidOne program, i.e. it has the standard Google dialer app installed.

The display settings in the app are set to "Sort by Last Name" and "Display first name first".

I have the following issue: When I search for a contact in the dialer app and type a last name of the contact in the search field, the correct contact is not found. Only if I type the first name in the search field, does the contact get found.

If I search for contacts in the Contacts app (also by Google), the contacts are correctly found regardless of which part of the contact I type in.

Why is there this difference? I'd expect the dialer app to also find contacts by any part. The dialer app has the access permission to contacts on the phone.

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: Hmm, I just tried searching by first name, middle name, and last name on Google's [Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer) app and it works though.

Comment: It does not work for me. Some names are found correctly, but for some others, results are displayed that are absolutely not related to the input in the search field. I tried to delete the google account from my phone and reattach it, but it didn't help.

Comment: I have the opposite problem in fact. I can search for Last Name only using the dialer. Matching first names don't appear. When I do 'search contacts & places', I am able to search on both first and last name.